# node.js http agent with proxy

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
this.agent = new HttpsProxyAgent("http://example.proxy.com");
```

however i need to add a set node.js original agent setting as well.

```
http.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
```

I donot see an option with httpsproxyagent to set this, as https-proxy-agent is derived from `agent-base`. Is there a way to achieve this with a different node.js module?

Answer (score 0):

I used the [`hpagent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hpagent) module.
It has `keepAlive: true` by default.

The `https-proxy-agent` has [a PR](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent/pull/112) to add this feature tho